# Prove that there is no norm for to make this mapping continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am dealing with an exercise which is as follows:
Show that there is no norm such that the set of all the mappings $T_a$ which map every element $f\in C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ (where the latter is the set of all continuous functions from reals to reals) to $f(a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$ are continuous. Can I get some hint to solve this?

Comment: This problem has the flavor of proof by contradiction; I.e., suppose such a norm exists, and try to arrive at a contradiction, perhaps by a clever choice of sequence $f_n$

Comment: Maybe a silly question: How can there be a well defined norm on $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$? For instance consider $f_k$ to be a non-zero continuous function with support in $(k,k+1)$, normalize it so that it has norm $1$. The sum of all $f_k$ is clearly a continuous function, but does not have a well defined norm...

Comment: @Qidi $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is a real vector space of dimension $2^{\aleph_0}$. Take any normed real vector space of that dimension, and transport the norm via a linear isomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose there exists such a norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ on $C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Then for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a constant $c_a > 0$ such that $$\lvert f(a) \rvert = \lvert T_a(f) \rvert \le c_a \lVert f \rVert$$ for all $f \in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. This is a contradiction because there exists continuous functions $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the set $$\left\{ \frac{\lvert f(a) \rvert}{c_a} \mid a \in \mathbb{R} \right\}$$ is not bounded.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see why existence of set of functions that there norm can increase is enough. This doesn't show there exist one with infinity norm right?

Comment: @Cupitor I am not talking about a set of functions. I am saying it's possible to find a single function $f$ such that the above set of real numbers is not bounded.

Comment: I think $f(a) = c_a a$ works right?

Comment: Or wait this might not be continuous.

Comment: @Cupitor You don't need $f(a) = c_a a$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$ ; it is enough to have $f(n) = c_n n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Very wise it is!

Comment: but wait a minute. $f(n)=nc_n$ is not continuous either.

Comment: @Cupitor What I am saying is that you choose the function $f$ so that $f(n) = nc_n$ when **$n$ is an integer.** Of course, you also need to define $f(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{N}$, but this can be done in such a way that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: I am so stupid! You are right!

Answer (score 0):

But there is such a norm. Just take the supremum norm.

*Added:* I am assuming that $C(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ is the set of bounded continuous functions.

Comment: Sup norm not is well defined cause domain is all $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't think there is, as far as my instructor told me. That being said I know that supp norm works when we consdier $C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: No I didn't mean that they are bounded! They can be unbounded.